# Oracle vs HANA char data type handling

Tags: oracle, hana, informatica-powercenter

We have Oracle as source and HANA 1.0 sps12 as target. We are mirroring Oracle to HANA with Informatica CDC through real-time replication. In Oracle, for many columns we have datatype as CHAR i.e. fixed length datatype. As HANA officially doesn't support CHAR datatype so we are using NVARCHAR data type instead of same. Problem we are facing is -as in Oracle CHAR datatype is of fixed length and append spaces whenever  actual string is of lesser length than datatype, we have lot of extra spaces in target HANA db for such columns.

For eg. If column col1 has data type

> CHAR(5)

and value as `'A'`, it is replicated in HANA as `'A    '` i.e. `'A'` appended by four extra spaces, causing lot of problems in queries and data interpretation

Is it possible to implement CHAR like datatype in HANA?

Comment: The fixed string length data type semantic is very “legacy”. Out of interest: what specifically do you need it for?

Comment: Source is SAP HYBRIS database. we have very little control over product tables.

Comment: In that case (SAP Hybris) the odd `CHAR` semantic is irrelevant. Remember that hybris is JAVA based and does not use fixed length strings. You’re safe with using `NVARCHAR` on HANA here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RPAD` function in Informatica while transferring data to Hana. Just make sure if Hana doesn't trim automatically.

So, for the CHAR(5) source column you should use:

```
out_Column = RPAD(input_Column, 5)
```

Pretty much exactly, as the documentation says: [image]

Comment: we are replicating it through informatica CDC...will using transformation affect performance of real time replication

Comment: Best  to do a test, but I wouldn't expect any major hit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know HANA and this is more a comment than an answer, but I chose to put it here as there's some code I'd like you to see.

Here's a table whose column is of a `CHAR` datatype:

```
SQL> create table test (col char(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values ('abc');

1 row created.
```

Column's length is 10 (which you already know):

```
SQL> select length(col) from test;

LENGTH(COL)
-----------
         10
```

But, if you **TRIM** it, you get a better result, the one you're looking for:

```
SQL> select length(  TRIM  (col)) from test;

LENGTH(TRIM(COL))
-----------------
                3

SQL>
```

So: if you can *persuade* the mirroring process to apply `TRIM` function to those columns, you might get what you want.

---

**[EDIT, after seeing Lars' comment and re-reading the question]**

Right; the problem seems to be just the opposite of what I initially understood. If that's the point, maybe `RPAD` would help. Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table test (col varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values ('abc');

1 row created.

SQL> select length(col) from test;

LENGTH(COL)
-----------
          3

SQL> insert into test values (rpad('def', 10, ' '));

1 row created.

SQL> select col, length(col) len from test;

COL               LEN
---------- ----------
abc                 3
def                10

SQL>
```

Comment: I understand the OPs question to be about the opposite effect, that is to *pad* the unused places in the fixed string length. `TRIM` takes those away.

Comment: Thank you, @Lars. It appears that I got it wrong. The opposite might be done with `RPAD` but - let's see what the OP says. If nothing of the above helps, I spend some time of my life in vain.